# undefined data using http.get() request to node.js from angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular

i'm trying to http.get() request to node.js from angular2

in CartService.ts..

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {

   private CartUrl: string = '../cart'; // URL to Web API
   private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

   constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public getCart(): Promise<Cart> {
        return this.http.get(this.CartUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Cart)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    public handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); 
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

}

and app.component.ts...

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor (private cartService: CartService){}

     cart : Lecture[] = [];
      DBinfo : Cart;


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCart();   
     }

     private getCart() : void{
         this.cartService.getCart()
              .then(DBinfo => this.DBinfo = DBinfo ,
                    ()=>console.log("The data is... "+this.DBinfo));

}
```

and index.js from nodejs..

```
router.get('/cart', function (req, res,next) {

    var cart = {
        "email": "sAAAA@gmail.com",
        "item" : "bread"
    };

    res.json(cart);
});
```

when ngOnInit excuted with this.getCart(),
console.log("The data is... "+this.DBinfo)); 
just printed that "The data is... undefined"

how can I get data from exactly from node.js..?

thanks for your time to read this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second callback from `then()` is the error-callback!

`.then(data => ..., err => console.log(err));`.

So as the second callback is executed, there seems to be any error during your request!

And your returned object from node.js has no `data` property:

`.then(response => response.json() as Cart)`

I would use `Observables`, this should do the trick:

```
public getCart(): Observable<Cart> {
   return this.http.get(this.CartUrl)
      .map(response => response.json() as Cart) // NO '.data' !!??
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

public handleError(error: any) {
   console.error('An error occurred', error); 
   return Observable.of(null);
}

private getCart(): void {
   this.cartService.getCart()
      .subscribe(DBinfo => this.DBinfo = DBinfo,
                 err => console.log(err),
                 () => console.log('done'));
}
```

Comment: i fix it
 `()=>console.log("The data is... "+this.DBinfo);` to `err => console.log(err)`, then trying to console.log(DBinfo) later, but same result appear...

Comment: Make an additional `console.log` into the first callback: `data => { console.log(data); this.data = data; }`

Comment: you means that fix it getCart `.then(DBinfo => {console.log(this.DBinfo); this.DBinfo = DBinfo} , err => console.log(err));`? its the same 'undefined'

Comment: I dont want to fix something, I want to FIND the error.. so which `console.log` is fired? first? second? both? none? .. need infos :)

Comment: print `DBinfo` or print it after it was assigned!

Comment: when i fix getCart in app.component.ts `.then(DBinfo => {this.DBinfo = DBinfo; console.log(this.DBinfo); } , err => console.log(err));`    it print undefined and none of error occured. and later check DBinfo, same 'undefined' printed

Comment: Then print that `response` to console, before using it. seems like inside of your service something goes wrong..

Comment: Is there a special reason to use `Promises` instead of `Observables`??

Comment: Why u are doing this `json().data`? guess that `.data` is wrong.

Comment: hmm... i don't know whether I should use Promise or Obsevables.. so i use Promise... is it better using Obsevable?

Comment: I would recommend to use `Observables` cause its the Angular standard.. See my updated answer and try this.

Comment: i changed Promise to Observables, then work!  i certainly appreciate your helping me out. thx so much :)